# Trying to convert string returned by "fread" to "base 16". PHP

Tags: php

What base type returned by the function "fread()" of PHP, and how can I convert this type to be shown as hexa on the screen?

```
If I do it that way:

while(!feof($resource))
{
    $contents = fread($resource, 1);
    $new = intval($contents);
    echo base_convert($new, 10, 16);
}
```

Its just prints a bunch of zeros on the screen...
Why its not the same as doing

```
$contents = fread($resource, filesize($file_text));
echo bin2hex($contents);
```

Which prints the normal hexa?

Comment: [fread()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) returns a String

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you see the question I edited?

Comment: `intval()` converts types to an `int` using integer casting rules. It does not find the integer value of a char. Meanwhile, `bin2hex()` takes binary data (ie characters) and converts it to its hex representation. See [this example](https://ideone.com/gFeiP6). Assuming your text file contains something other than numbers, `bin2hex()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "not the same" because `intval` does not do what you think it does.  It takes a string and interprets it as an integer.  If the string has letters and such in it, it's not a valid integer, and so `intval` returns 0.

That function is for converting e.g. "1234567"(string) to 1234567(int).